# Text And Button in Full Width Image

Tags: html, css, image, position

I have a page wherein I have multiple full-width `<img>`'s - I have to add a `<button>` and `<h2>` overlaid upon each image. Images will have variable heights, so elements within need to conform to the perimeter set by their width + height.

An image is styled thus:

CSS

```
.FullWidthImg {
   width: 100vw;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   right: 50%;
   margin-left: -50vw;
   margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container"> <!--ONLY STYLING FOR container IS position: relative-->
  <img src="xx" alt="xx" style="FullWidthImg"/>
  <h2>TEXT GOES HERE</h2>
  <button>i'm a button</button>
</div>
```

Most approaches suggest styling `<h2>` and `<button>` with `position: absolute` - this works if you have one image element and the image always has the same height, however neither is the case for me.

Another approach I've seen is making something like:

```
<div style="background-image: url(/img.com)">
  <h2>TEXT GOES HERE</h2>
  <button>i'm a button</button>
</div>
```

... And then positioning elements within, which could work but I'd like to avoid in-line styling if possible.

Are there any alternative approaches that would work for this use-case?

Comment: I don't consider either solution you've proposed hacky. Regarding the first solution - "this works if you have one image element and the image always has the same height" - all you need is to wrap each group of img, h2 and button inside separate divs.

Comment: Why does the second option have to be inline styling? Just add a unique id or class and move the style to your CSS file.

Comment: @William_Wilson Unless there's something I'm not aware of, you need inline-styling because each `background-image` has to be different. If you use a class, you can only have one image. If you use ID's - you have to create a separate ID for each image. You could still use a class/id but would need to change the `background-image` using `style`, inline.

Comment: I guess I don't see the difference in where the separate images are defined as there will be separate source info regardless. E.g. in the img tags, inline div styling or as separate ids/classes. Just pointing out that it seem like the only thing forcing your inline styling is a preference to define the image sources in the html file, not html/css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building off your first suggestion, here's how you could accomplish your desired layout without inline styles.

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-wrapper .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-wrapper h2 {
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x150/eee/ddd" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x400/eee/ddd" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this approach now